# Python - Extract string from a text file until the first 2 new line space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input file from while I have to extract few lines based on 2 blank new lines.

For eg: The text file is like below.

```
1. Sometext
Sometext 
Sometext

2. Sometext
Sometext
Sometext

3. Sometext
Sometext
Sometext

Sometext which is not needed
Sometext which is not needed
Sometext which is not needed
```

I have to extract a substring stating from "1." to all before "2."
and the 2nd substring from "2." to all before "3." and so on based on the numbers. I have the below script which gets the output but it also gets all of "Sometext which is not needed" which i do not want. Please see the code below:

```
file_path = open("filename", "r")
content = file_path.read()
size1 = len(content)
start =0
a=1
b=2
end =0
ext =0   

while (start<size):
   if (end !=-1):
   subString = content[content.find(str(a)+".")+0:content.find("\n"+str(b)+".")] 
   print (subString)
   end = content.find(str(b)+".",start)
                print ("\n")
                a = int(a)+1 # increment to find the next start number
                b = int(b)+1 # increment to find the next end number
                start = end+1 # continuing to search the next
            else:
                break
```

So, I decided to find for 2 continuous blank lines for the end position and used the below one but that didnt work.

```
subString = content[content.find (str(a)+".")+3:content.find("\n\n")]
```

Please help and let me know if you have any questions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does "Sometext which is not needed" differ from the other lines? Is it at the end of file or something?

Comment: Is your sample data formatted correctly? It appears there are 3 newlines between every line.

Comment: @GriMel.. "Sometext which is not needed" doesn't start with a number after 2 new lines

Comment: @glibdud.. Sorry, I tried formatting with 2 newlines but the text comes all in just one line.. So I had to edit it this way. Please consider this as an example with just 2 lines separation.

Comment: Please see the edit I suggested... does that accurately represent what the data looks like?

Comment: Great.. Thanks @glibdud.. The data looks correct now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but here is the code that will output:

```
['Sometext', 'Sometext', 'Sometext']
['Sometext', 'Sometext', 'Sometext']
['Sometext', 'Sometext', 'Sometext']
```

based on the text in your question. If instead you want 1 to 2 to be a whole substring like this:

```
['1. Sometext\nSometext\nSometext']
['2. Sometext\nSometext\nSometext']
['3. Sometext\nSometext\nSometext']
```

You should change the if statement to:

```
if is_number(i[0]):
            substring = []
            substring.append(i)
            print(substring)
```

else you can use the code below

```
def is_number(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

with open('testing.txt', 'r') as f:
content = f.read().split('\n\n')
for i in content:
    if is_number(i[0]):
        c = i.split('\n')
        substring = [line[3:] if is_number(line[0]) else line for line in c]
        print(substring)
```

Comment: ..I am sorry if I wasn't clear enough. You code works fine but it works only when the start of the line contains "1."
I basically wanted to find the first occurrence of "1."  anywhere in the file and continues to find the last number (in the example it is "3."  but could be anything). which ends with 2 new lines. I will try to modify your code a little and see if that help.. but if you could get it, please let me know. thank you very much and let me know if I am still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to filter the unwanted lines at the end but this will get you want you want:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open("in.txt") as f:
    grps = groupby(f, key=lambda x: bool(x.strip()))
    print([list(v) for k,v in grps if k])
```

Output:

```
[['1. Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n'], ['2. Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n'], ['3. Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n'], ['Sometext which is not needed\n', 'Sometext which is not needed\n', 'Sometext which is not needed']]
```

Since all the sections you want to keep start with a digit:

```
from itertools import groupby, takewhile

with open("in.txt") as f:
    grps = groupby(f, key=lambda x: bool(x.strip()))
    print (list(takewhile(lambda x: x[0][0].isdigit(),(list(v) for k,v in grps if k))))
```

Output:

```
[['1. Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n'],
 ['2. Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n'],
['3. Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n']]
```

If you know there are `n` groups you could slice:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice
with open("in.txt") as f:
    grps = groupby(f, key=lambda x: bool(x.strip()))
    print (list(islice((list(v) for k,v in grps if k),3)))
```

Output:

```
[['1. Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n'],
 ['2. Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n'], 
['3. Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n', 'Sometext\n']]
```

Comment: Thank you Padraic. You code works but it puts the complete file as one value. I need the values to be split (3 values as per the example). Also, it appends with \n. How will I remove that?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Sanjivi, are you sure there are always 3 sections? Also it is in three sections,each sublist is a section, to remove the newlines we just need to strip them off

Comment: apologies for the delayed response.
Nope, there can be many sections. I have shown 3 just for an example. 
yes, each sublist is a section separated by 3 blank new lines.
I wanted to extract each sublist as a single substring and feed it to my system.